# PHP7.2 unable to load rdkafka

Tags: php, apache2, librdkafka

I need to install rdkafka on Ubuntu20 with Apache2 web server for a Laravel project. The PHP version is 7.2. I followed the documentation in [Official Link](https://arnaud.le-blanc.net/php-rdkafka-doc/phpdoc/rdkafka.installation.manual.html) and it finally shows

> Installing '/usr/lib/php/20200930/rdkafka.so'

Now I see the warning

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'rdkafka.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

The command `php -i | grep extension_dir` gives me

> extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20170718 => /usr/lib/php/20170718

It seems the `rdkafka.so` is installed inside a directory where `PHP7.2` doesn't load its modules. If I manually move the `rdkafka.so` from `/usr/lib/php/20200930` to `/usr/lib/php/20170718` - as documentation suggested - it reports the error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'rdkafka.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so: undefined symbol: zend_string_init_interned), /usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/rdkafka.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP 7.2.34-24+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2021 15:55:49) ( NTS )

The error `undefined symbol: zend_string_init_interned` shows up.

What shall I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by install `php7.2-dev` which contains `phpize7.2` and uninstalling `php*-dev` to make sure only `phpize` and `phpize7.2` are installed. Then it installed the `rdkafka` in the right directory.